# Save list of enums in database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have `List<object>` list of enums that is the result of some pattern matching code I wrote.

My problem is that I want to save this list of enums in the database so this pattern can be applied again in the future but I am a bit puzzled how to do this.

The enum list comprises of different enums, for instance:

```
EnumType1.SomeVaue
EnumType2.SomeValue
```

Also I do not know how many enums or in what order they will be.  I am struggling to think of a good way to serialise this to the database so the `List<object>` list can be re-created later with the same enums to feed back into my code.

I am wondering if representing pattern segments with enums was a bad idea and I should go back and refactor all the code?

Can I turn the enum to a string including the enum type and then convert it back?

Comment: do you need to know how to save `enums` on the db or what ?

Comment: I want to store the list of enums in its exact order.  I can set the enum as a property but I want the list of enums saved together so I can re-create it later.

Answer (score 0):

You could save the different enum **int** values into the database. for example

```
public enum Animal {Dog = 0, Cat = 1, Bird = 2}
public class Person
{
    public Animal Pet {get; private set;}

    public Person()
    {
        Pet = Animal.Dog;
    }

    public void Insert()
    {
        using(var con = DbFactory.CreateConnection(Database))
        {
            con.Query("stored_procedure_here", new { Pet = this.Pet}, CommandType.StoredProcedure);
        }
    }


}
```

In Your Database you will have a table with Pet as an integer. The integer value of **Dog** which is **0** will be saved. then when you pull the value of the enum (**0**) the enum will automatically know that it is dog.. i hope that made sense... new to this whole answering on stackoverflow thingy :))

**EDIT:**
Ok if you have multiple types of enums in the list you could have a table that holds the **int** value and also another column that has the **Type/Name** of the enum. when you pull it out you could have some sort of logic that sort of organizes it into the appropriate enum.. i guess..

```
 //Get the Name/Type and the int from the database for example Dog, 0
 string enumName = "Dog";
 int enumValue = 0
 Type enumType = Type.GetType(enumName);
 if (enumType == null)
 {
     throw new ArgumentException("Specified enum type could not be     found", "enumName");
 }

 object value = Enum.Parse(enumType, enumValue);
```

}

Comment: I have multiple different enum types in the list so it would not work.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I will have to look into creating enum type from string and I am not sure on how to reverse the process.

Comment: @Guerrilla have edited my answer i hope this may help.. possibly having the Enum "name" and value inside a table then you can figure out the type of enum and int and get the enum value you desire that way???